# Minecraft - Authentication servers aren't connecting to my Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, java

Server Information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Java: 1.8.0_45
```

For some odd reason, I can't join any of my [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net/en-us/) servers because the game says Authentication failed (This error is printed when the server hosting the game can't connect to the session servers of the game, you can see at help.mojang.com all their servers are online and I shouldn't be having this problem unless there's a network issue on my end). I am able to join other servers just fine, but mine don't work. I have ping-ed google successfully using Ubuntu's ping program. I had one of my friends join the same server and were unsuccessful. I have copied files from another Ubuntu 16 server, I can join those Minecraft servers just fine, I pasted them on to the suspect server and started it, it did not work. It has to be something to do with it not communicating with the authentication servers or something network wise as the good dedicated is on a totally different network.

Please note: I have tried both my domain and the normal IP as well as no [multicraft](https://www.multicraft.org/) and multicraft. If you're curious, I have tried 1.7.10, 1.8.9 and 1.11.2 versions of Minecraft, none worked.

If you can help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have firewall rules in place? Is it a modded server? Does the log of the server provide further information? Have you tried to ping the authentication servers (authserver.mojang.com)?

Comment: @Seth I do not believe there is any fire wall changes that would affect this as I have not touched it on either server and it only works on one. It is a vanilla server, for all three version, no matter what I can't join. The minecraft logs only show the server starting and when I join the message it always prints when someone fails to join. (Normally along the lines, 'Player x disconnect because Authentication servers are down'). I have no pinged the auth server since I couldn't find the address for it, I will try that now.

Comment: I have pinged the auth server (authserver.mojang.com) successfully on my local pc and the two Ubuntu servers.

Comment: Did it work before? If it did and you really didn't change the configuration maybe you're blocked for some kind of behavior? Do you have a lot of users on that server? If the other server is on a different network either that network might block the traffic that is being generated or that network is denied access. Though I would expect you not to be able to ping the auth server in that case.

Comment: I just got this new dedicated last night, and I was still not able to connect even when I originally installed Minecraft. We have very few users, maybe around 20 or less on another game they can connect fine on.

Comment: @Seth After rebooting the dedicated I am still getting the same error. Since this error is located on my host's end of things, should I contact them?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the pest way to progress. As you're apparently able to reach the server it's kind of odd that you're not able to get the client to connect. You could try to contact the provider and let them check on their end if they can see anything but it's not that likely that they will actually do that. Alternatively you could ask for a new IP for the server, in order to minimize the possibility that it's banned or you could run it in offline mode (strongly discouraged).

Comment: @Seth Well, I asked my provider for a little assistance, they said it could be a hardware issue since I moved from an Intel processor to an AMD, I ruled this out by creating an entirely new server. After I told them about the server being able to ping the authentication servers but not being able to connect proper they said it's not a network error and they can't help any further since it's an unmanaged host. Just in case Mojang did black list the IP, I sent them an email stating this IP is under new management and should be back in the okay list. If this is not the case, I have no clue.

Comment: @Seth I have found a site that confirmed that my IP is not black listed. Now we're back to square one, why would this happen? Why would my server be unable to connect to the authentication servers? I have tried all sorts of different server jars, minecraft versions, I've looked up page after page on google about this. I can't find anything, it's like I'm the only one with this problem. I even contacted a friend who's played Minecraft since beta and has learned Java not long after, he said he's never seen it. Me, being an experienced user myself, I'm clueless.

Comment: Did you check whenever `iptables -L` would list anything that might interfere? Did you check that you have the same and only one java version installed on both servers (in doubt try to match your working server)? Do have an IPv4 and IPv6 address on the server and are you able to use the IPv6 address to access the internet? I did have an issue before (on Windows) where Java was trying to use the link local address and never got anywhere.

Comment: @Seth [This](http://pastebin.com/9zrZ1DDJ) shows up when I use `iptables -L` and I have the same Java, Java 8 update 45. I've even tried reinstalling it. I do not have an IPv6 and I am able to connect to the IPv4.

Comment: @Seth Something interesting has been happening when a mod or plugin attempts to check for valid UUIDs. [This](https://pastebin.com/LDCS2njx) is what happens when ProjectE with Tekkit Legends tries to connect to Mojang for UUID confirmation. Something to do with SSL? I'm not good in Java, maybe this will further the investigation a little.

Comment: From what I can see it would/could indicate a missing/damaged store for the certs. See also [Minecraft with OpenJDK 7, I get “the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627426/minecraft-with-openjdk-7-i-get-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty). This could indicate that your installation is just broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of research and help from wonderful people here at Superuser, I have finally got the servers to be able to accept premium players on online mode. I no longer have any SSL errors. Here's what I did:

After @Seth gave me a link to another post related to a recent error I got, I put a simple command line in the console and the servers were able to start on online mode.

Link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/627426/minecraft-with-openjdk-7-i-get-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Command line code:
`sudo update-ca-certificates -f`

Comment: If you would've mentioned those errors it could've been solved a bit faster. If you run into such a problem again and possibly have actual errors in the log, consider posting the log in addition to your question. Possibly using pastebin or a similar service. Sorry that it didn't cross my mind to ask for that information. :D Best of luck with your server.